# Sort array in specific way

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Hello i've tried to sort array in this special case

a) Odd numbers which are divisible by 3 must come first ascendingly

b) Even numbers which are divisible by 3 must come last descendingly

c) Numbers which are not divisible by 3 are sorted ascendingly

this is my code

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;

bool cmp(int b,int a){

    if((b%2 && b%3==0) && (a%2==0 || a%3 || b>a) )
        return true ;

    if((a%2==0 && a%3==0) && (b%2 || b%3) )
        return true ;

    return false ;
}

int main(){

int ar[8]={18 ,5 ,24 ,9 ,12 ,6 ,2, 3};

sort(ar,ar+8,cmp);

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    cout<<ar[i]<<endl ;

return 0;
}
```

my output

9
3
5
2
18
24
12
6

Excepted

3 9 2 5 24 18 12 6

so now the array is dvided to 3 blocks but not sorted as the special case i mentioned above

Comment: Please also add the output you expect and the output you actually get.

Comment: sorry ,i've added it now

Comment: Ok, so it's partitioned correctly, but each partition is not sorted correctly. I'm having a look now, think I'm just gonna rewrite your comparator to be clearer.

Comment: Are you sure your compare function is following the [compare concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) properly, including the [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)? More generally I don't think the `std::sort` function seems to be the right choice here, at least not by it self, maybe you need some kind of [partitioning](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Partitioning_operations) first?

Comment: @BoBTFish i'm waiting :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg why do u think the std::sort not the right choice here ?

Comment: Because sorting isn't for partitioning. Instead I suggest you first partition the array, and then sort each partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your comparison function is quite complex, I've rewritten it very verbosely, so each possible case can be inspected separately. I've also separated into a different function the decision about which partition of the output each element goes into.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int classify(int const i)
{
    if (i%3==0 && i%2!=0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (i%3!=0) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 3;
    }
}

bool comp(int const a, int const b)
{
    int const a_part = classify(a);
    int const b_part = classify(b);

    if (a_part==1) {
        if (b_part==1) {
            // both in first partition, order ascending
            return a<b;
        }
        else {
            // a in first partition, b not, so a always first
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (a_part==2) {
        if (b_part==1) {
            // b comes before a
            return false;
        }
        else if (b_part==2) {
            // both in middle partition, order ascendingly
            return a<b;
        }
        else {
            // a in middle partition, b in last partition, so a always first
            return true;
        }
    }
    else { // (a_part==3)
        if (b_part!=3) {
            // a in last partition, b in first or middle partition,
            // so b always comes first
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // both in last partition, order descending
            return b<a;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int ar[8] = {18 ,5 ,24 ,9 ,12 ,6 ,2, 3};
    std::sort(std::begin(ar),
              std::end(ar),
              comp);
    std::copy(std::begin(ar),
              std::end(ar),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,
                                         "\n"));
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./SO 
3
9
2
5
24
18
12
6
```

Bear in mind your comparator must induce a [**Strict Weak Ordering**](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), which I *think* this does, but it's a bit trickier than one would normally use for sorting.

Always write your code as *clearly* as possible, not as *short* as possible. If you have some complicated logic, break it up, move parts out into functions, and add plenty of comments. Remember, other people have to read and understand it, including yourself in 6 months.

---

What might be a better approach is to split the sort up. You are really talking about splitting the array into 3 partitions, each being treated differently. So use [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) twice, and [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) three times. I think that may well be more understandable. This code has the exact same output as the above:

```
bool isOddMultipleOfThree(int const i)
{
    return (i%3==0 && i%2!=0);
}

bool isEvenMultipleOfThree(int const i)
{
    return (i%3==0 && i%2==0);
}

int main()
{
    int ar[8] = {18 ,5 ,24 ,9 ,12 ,6 ,2, 3};

    // split off the first partition
    auto firstSplit = std::partition(std::begin(ar),
                                     std::end(ar),
                                     isOddMultipleOfThree);
    // sort the first partition
    std::sort(std::begin(ar),
              firstSplit,
              std::less<int>());

    // split off end partition
    // use a lambda to invert the predicate, because we want the matching
    // values pushed to the end
    auto secondSplit = std::partition(firstSplit,
                                      std::end(ar),
                                      [](int const i) {
                                        return !isEvenMultipleOfThree(i);
                                      });

    // sort middle partition
    std::sort(firstSplit,
              secondSplit,
              std::less<int>());
    // sort last partition
    std::sort(secondSplit,
              std::end(ar),
              std::greater<int>());

    // print
    std::copy(std::begin(ar),
              std::end(ar),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,
                                         "\n"));
}
```

---

Also worth mentioning, many people (myself included) consider [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`std::endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html) are bad practices.

Comment: You can take this approach but make it a lot simpler, once you have filled in `a_part` and `b_part`: `if (a_part != b_part) return a_part < b_part;` It will probably be clear how to continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) to first "split" your array into three partitions, and then sorting each partition, you will get something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 8> array = {{ 18 ,5 ,24 ,9 ,12 ,6 ,2, 3 }};

    std::cout << "Before first partitioning: ";
    for (auto const value : array)
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // First partition putting all odd number even divisible by three first
    auto second_start = std::partition(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [](int const& value) {
        return (value % 2 != 0 && value % 3 == 0);
    });

    std::cout << "Before second partitioning: ";
    for (auto const value : array)
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Then partition putting all even number even divisible by three first
    auto third_start = std::partition(second_start, std::end(array), [](int const& value) {
        return !(value % 2 == 0 && value % 3 == 0);
    });

    std::cout << "Before sorting: ";
    for (auto const value : array)
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::sort(std::begin(array), second_start, std::less<int>());
    std::sort(second_start, third_start, std::less<int>());
    std::sort(third_start, std::end(array), std::greater<int>());

    std::cout << "After sorting: ";
    for (auto const value : array)
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
Before first partitioning: 18 5 24 9 12 6 2 3 
Before second partitioning: 3 9 24 5 12 6 2 18 
Before sorting: 3 9 2 5 12 6 24 18 
After sorting: 3 9 2 5 24 18 12 6
```

The output after soring is as what you expect.

See [here](http://ideone.com/93bNNV) for it in "action".

It is more work, but is also guaranteed to behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This simple comparison function works for me:

```
bool cmp(int lhs, int rhs){
    bool lhs_div_3 = lhs % 3 == 0;
    bool rhs_div_3 = rhs % 3 == 0;
    bool lhs_odd = lhs & 1;
    bool rhs_odd = rhs & 1;

    if (lhs_div_3 && lhs_odd) // lhs in class a)
        if (rhs_div_3 && rhs_odd)
            return lhs < rhs;
        else 
            return true;

    if (!lhs_div_3) // lhs in class c)
        if (!rhs_div_3)
            return lhs < rhs;
        else
            return !rhs_odd;

    // else lhs in class b) 
    if (rhs_div_3 && !rhs_odd)
        return rhs < lhs;

    return false;
}
```

But if you have large arrays and care about performance, you should likely partition data first and then sort each 3 parts independently as recommended by others (to avoid such a complex, i.e., slow comparison function).

Answer (score 1):

I would construct a tuple for that `{partition1, partition2, order}`:

```
auto helper(int i)
{
    bool isEven = i % 2 == 0;
    bool isMul3 = i % 3 == 0;
    return std::make_tuple(!(!isEven && isMul3), // partition 1
                           isEven && isMul3,     // partition2
                           isEven && isMul3 ? -i : i); // order
}

bool cmp(int lhs, int rhs){
    return helper(lhs) < helper(rhs);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c36eac416b99594)